# CORS with Authorization fails (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)

Tags: spring, angularjs, cors

Sorry for posting this rather large post. But I don't see a way to get it any smaller. Blame CORS :)

**Versions:**

- Angularjs Version: 1.1.3
- Jetty Version: 8.1.9
- Jetty Servlets Version: 8.1.9.v20130131 (Used for Jettys CrossOriginFilter)

**What I want to achieve**

Cross Origin Request using Basic Authorization header:

- with $http method from Angularjs originating from localhost:8000
- to localhost:8080/api/user (Spring MVC REST interface).

**Issue:**

- HTTPFox shows that OPTIONS request to /api/user was denied with Response 302 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)
- Server is responding with 302 instead of 200 if Authorization Basic header is sent.
- So called Simple CORS headers work (without Angularjs Authorization Basic header set).
- Angularjs returns 0 as status (instead of 302 or 200).
- In the Response Header of HTTPFox Location header redirects as if Authorization failed
- Tests with Curl (with Authorization Header set) work without any issues
- Supplied Base64 encoded Authorization String is correct.

**Questions:**

- What is the reason for OPTIONS 302 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)? How can I solve it?
- Why does Angularjs return 0 instead of 302 or 200 (seems an issue with x-requested-with)?
- Is using Cross Origin with browsers really a good idea for production (it seems like there are many issues)?

**CORS settings in web.xml of Spring configuration:**

```
allowedOrigins: *
allowedMethods: GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,HEAD,OPTIONS
allowedHeaders: origin,content-type,accept,authorization,x-requested-with
supportsCredentials: true
```

**Angularjs http request (Origins from: localhost:8000):**

```
$http.get('localhost:8080/api/user', {headers: {'Authorization':'Basic am9obkBqb2huLmNvbTpibGE='}})
  .success(function(data, status, head, config) {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(status);
  })
  .error(function(data, status, head, config) {
    console.log("error");
    console.log(status);
  });
```

**HTTPFox Request Headers (from OPTIONS request that fails):**

```
(Request-Line)  OPTIONS /api/user HTTP/1.1
Host    localhost:8080
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate DNT   1
Origin  localhost:8000
Access-Control-Request-Method   GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers  authorization
Connection  keep-alive
```

**HTTPFox Response Headers (from OPTIONS request that fails):**

```
(Status-Line)   HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Access-Control-Allow-Origin localhost:8000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    true
Access-Control-Max-Age  1800
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,HEAD,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    origin, content-type, accept, authorization, x-requested-with
Location    localhost:8080/login.jsp
Content-Length  0
Server  Jetty(8.1.9.v20130131)
```

**Spring DEBUG Log:**

```
[qtp1172726060-24 - /api/user] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - REQUEST /api/user on AsyncHttpConnection@c114739,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-5,l=10,c=0},r=1
[qtp1172726060-24 - /api/user] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - chain=CORS->springSecurityFilterChain->spring
[qtp1172726060-24 - /api/user] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - call filter CORS
[qtp1172726060-24 - /api/user] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter - Cross-origin request to /api/user is a preflight cross-origin request
[qtp1172726060-24 - /api/user] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter - Access-Control-Request-Method is GET
[qtp1172726060-24 - /api/user] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter - Method GET is among allowed methods [GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, HEAD, OPTIONS]
[qtp1172726060-24 - /api/user] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter - Access-Control-Request-Headers is authorization
[qtp1172726060-24 - /api/user] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter - Headers [authorization] are among allowed headers [origin,  content-type,  accept,  authorization,  x-requested-with]
[qtp1172726060-24 - /api/user] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter - Preflight cross-origin request to /api/user forwarded to application
[qtp1172726060-24 - /api/user] DEBUG o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - call filter springSecurityFilterChain
[qtp1172726060-24 - /api/user] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - RESPONSE /api/user  302 handled=true
[qtp1172726060-24] DEBUG o.e.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection - Enabled read interest SCEP@5deb702b{l(/127.0.0.1:41667)<->r(/127.0.0.1:8080),d=true,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0r}-{AsyncHttpConnection@c114739,g=HttpGenerator{s=4,h=0,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=0,l=10,c=0},r=1}
```

**Web.xml:**

```
<!-- CORS related filter (this comes before the security filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>origin, content-type, accept, authorization, x-requested-with</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Security related filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Disable springSecurityFilterChain works, put it back in, doesn't work. The error message is comming from the browser for sure and seems to be an old Netscape message. However I experience the same issues in Chrome. So either I need to configure something differently in web.xml allowing OPTIONS to do something it can't do at the moment due to the dispatchingservlet or springsecurityfilterchain or if this isn't it then this CORS stuff simply is not usable yet with Authorization headers in certain browsers.... I have been reading nearly through all the specs.

Answer (score 1):

We use CORS in production but it will only work on HTML5 complaint browsers, and we had the same problems.

The only difference between our client-side and yours is that you are not passing the withCredentials to the get method.

Like this:

```
$http.get(url, { withCredentials : true })
```

You can also set as default:

```
config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}]);
```

If neither of this work, try changing your CORS servlet to [this](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html).

Comment: I tried withCredentials and it didn't work either. At the moment I decided to go without CORS. Maybe I'll try to use it again in 1-2 years until the majority of browsers support it and it has been implemented correctly by all frameworks and technologies. thanks anyway. it's good to know that it works for some people already. for the moment i can live with deploying client and server part in one jar and load balancing between servers.